# Python Playwright, how to fill data into these boxes

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I am writing a Python script using the Playwright package to auto-complete a questionnaire. [Here is a dummy version of the form](https://ee.kobotoolbox.org/x/cmKGMgos), and here is my code so far:

```py
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def form_entry():
    async with async_playwright() as pw:
        browser = await pw.chromium.launch(
            headless=False
        )

        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto('https://ee.kobotoolbox.org/x/cmKGMgos')
        await page.wait_for_timeout(3000)

        await page.get_by_label("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD:").fill("123")
        await page.get_by_label('Q4 (Oct-Nov)').check()
        await page.get_by_label('A').check()
        
        ### code to enter values in the 6 boxes in section 1.1 

        await browser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(form_entry())
```

This code can input/select the correct responses to the first few questions (Quarter, Year, Enter your password, name of the company), but I can't get it to work for the input boxes in section 1.1 (3 boxes each for `NO. OF MEN:` & `NO. OF WOMEN:`)

In the html I can see the `<input ...` with `type="number"` and `name="/a8v6GUnyWqGLNQoNqnNkps/level_1/level_1_1/cc_1a_num_men_m1"`, so I would have thought that

```py
await page.get_by_role('number',name='/a8v6GUnyWqGLNQoNqnNkps/level_1/level_1_1/cc_1a_num_men_m1').fill(12)
```

would work, but it doesn't.

Can anyone advise the correct syntax to fill numbers into these 6 boxes? Like this:
[image: Example ideal output]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Playwright you can give a very generic CSS or Xpath, and select the nth element that corresponds to the element you need:

```
self.page.locator('CSS-EXPRESSION').nth(5)
```

So, you can select input type in the CSS expression, and send the relevant index number.

Instead of fill or type, you can use Playwright built-in keyboard:

```
self.page.keyboard.type('YourTextHere')
```